# Orderby queries causing some issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code in my functions.php file in order to display results in a particular order...

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
        if( is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'book' ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');   
        $query->set('meta_key', 'start_date');   
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');   
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');



function wpse139657_orderby($query){ 

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'book_release_date' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );

        if (is_admin() || $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'book') return $query;
} 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');
```

The problem is that the above code is causing some kind of conflicts with other function queries, which stopped working.

I'm pretty sure I should fix this part of code: `if (is_admin() || $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'book') return $query;` but still, I can't figure out how to properly type it. Can you help me?

EDIT: 
The following query is being interrupted by the above code for weird reasons. It used to work until I used the above function, that somehow deactivated this one to work:

```
function haruki($post_id) {
global $post;
$thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$images = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );
if ($images) :
foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :
if ( $image->ID != $thumbnail_ID ) :
$img_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); //alt
if ($img_alt == '') : $img_alt = $image->post_title; endif;
$big_array = image_downsize( $image->ID, 'large' );
$img_url = $big_array[0];
echo $img_url;
endif; endforeach; endif; }
```

Comment: _Which_ other queries get affected, and which ones _do_ you actually want to affect? In your first function, you are checking if the query post type is `book`, in your second one your are manipulating _every_ query that is _not_ post type `movie`. We can’t tell you if that is correct or not, because you simply have not given us significant info yet.

Comment: @04FS sorry I copy pasted a wrong part coz I was still editing. Second one was book again, NOT movie. I have corrected it. Also, I have updated my question and explained which query stopped working coz of my main code.

Comment: Okay then first of all, why are you using two different ways, to do the same thing? (Your second function is not even returning the query in some cases, not sure if it is even supposed to work then.) `get_children` in your last function basically passes the parameters on to `get_posts`, but in there the post type `attachment` is requested, so _in theory_ this should not affect that query then.

Comment: I’d suggest you do some debugging inside of your own `pre_get_posts` handler functions then, to see what the queries passed in to them look like. That should help you figure out what specifically you need to check for to correctly exclude them at this point then.

Comment: I must admit the pre_get_posts thing is there just because I thought it was useful as a part of the second code, to make it work. But the pre_get_posts alone doesn't seem to work. It isn't giving me what expected. It doesn't change anything. I have then removed it from my functions.php file and kept the function wpse139657_orderby only. The problem is how can I make a debugging to figure out why is this causing the function haruki to stop working? (Sorry I have not much competence)